# Break debugger whenever event is fired in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, events, break

just a little question: Is it possible for the debugger to do a break whenever an event is firing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which event? Subscribe to it, put breakpoint, voila..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Let me explain:

I'm in the debugger mode. I want a break whenever any existing event in the code is firing. I have like 100000 lines of code with like 200 events. I just want to have a break too see whenever ANY EXISTING EVENT is firing. 

I hope you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't register a global handler for *all* events that raise on an application, but you can actually register your own handler for static events, with the help of Reflection:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo handler = typeof(Program).GetMethod("GlobalEventHandler");
        IEnumerable<EventInfo> events = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .Select(a => a.GetTypes()
                          .Select(t => t.GetEvents(
                                            BindingFlags.Public |
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                            BindingFlags.Static)
                                         .Where(e => typeof(EventHandler)
                                                     .IsAssignableFrom(e.EventHandlerType))))
            .SelectMany(e => e)
            .SelectMany(e => e);

        foreach (EventInfo evt in events)
            evt.GetAddMethod(true).Invoke(null, new object[]
            {
                Delegate.CreateDelegate(evt.EventHandlerType, null, handler)
            });
    }

    public static void GlobalEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Debugger.Break(); // <-- When a static event is fired, the application will break here
        Console.WriteLine("An event was fired!");
    }
```

The supported static events are not that many.

**16 actually**:

1. [Application.ApplicationExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Application.Idle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Application.EnterThreadModal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enterthreadmodal(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. [Application.LeaveThreadModal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.leavethreadmodal(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. [Application.ThreadExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexit(v=vs.110).aspx)
6. [ToolStripManager.RendererChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontentpanel.rendererchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
7. [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanging(v=vs.110).aspx)
8. [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
9. [SystemEvents.EventsThreadShutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.eventsthreadshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx)
10. [SystemEvents.InstalledFontsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.installedfontschanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
11. [SystemEvents.LowMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.lowmemory(v=vs.110).aspx)
12. [SystemEvents.PaletteChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.palettechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
13. [SystemEvents.TimeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
14. [ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.threadidle(v=vs.110).aspx)
15. [ComponentDispatcher.EnterThreadModal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.enterthreadmodal(v=vs.110).aspx)
16. [ComponentDispatcher.LeaveThreadModal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.leavethreadmodal(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: care to share what libraries I need to import?